# html5 canvas: draw together

Tags: html, canvas

Now I'm developing a paint chat program using HTML5 canvas, and I meet a problem that two or more user draw on a same canvas at the same time.

Canvas have only one instance for each property, only one strokeStyle, one fillStyle, and so on. When two users draw on the same canvas; chaos ensues.

I've tried using more canvases that have the same positioning, but when and how to exchange two canvases' data is a problem.

Does anyone know any other ways to do so, or how can I exchange data between canvases properly?

EDIT:

I think I didn't say it clearly enough. Now I have canvas, messages from server via socket.io, different painting requests on hand. When user moves his mouse to draw a line, the canvas now gets lineWidth, strokeStyle, globalOpacity. However, since canvas can only have one painter at one time, the draw requests from server, including another kind of painter, cannot be drawn at the same time. If we have enough user, the painting won't fluent.

I prepare to write a queue or something like it, to implement the function, but there might be other way to do it.

Comment: What did you mean when you said 'two or more user draw on a same canvas'???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each client needs to send the drawing commands to a server. The server should broadcast the commands to all clients. You need a method that receives the messages and draw them.

E.g. if the user can set attributes like e.g. "stroke size" and color, you also need to broadcast those changes.

You need to register mouse listeners for the users painting. They should call methods for painting e.g. `drawMoveTo` and `drawLineTo`, and also buffer the commands in a single path,  so you can broadcast the full path in the messages to the other clients.

Examples of messages could be:

```
{"clientId": 36, "penSize": 8, "color": "blue"}
{"clientId": 36, "command": {"moveTo", "x": 48, "y": 12}, 
                   "path": [{"moveTo", "x": 48, "y": 12}]}
{"clientId": 36, "command": {"lineTo", "x": 52, "y": 24}, 
                   "path": [{"lineTo", "x": 52, "y": 24}, 
                            {"moveTo", "x": 48, "y": 12}]}
{"clientId": 36, "command": {"lineTo", "x": 47, "y": 36}, 
                   "path": [{"lineTo", "x": 47, "y": 36},
                            {"lineTo", "x": 52, "y": 24},
                            {"moveTo", "x": 48, "y": 12}]}
```

You can have a datastructure to keep track of the "strokeAttributes" for each user. Then when you receive a message that is of type `moveTo` or `lineTo`, you lookup the `clientId` to get the stroke attributes e.g. `penSize` and `color`, then you call the same methods that is called when the local user paints, e.g. `drawMoveTo` and `drawLineTo`.

The `draw` methods has to use different strokes and attributes depending on from what client the message (or mouselistener) is coming from. It will change a lot, if multiple users draw concurrently.

I would recommedn that you do the communication using WebSockets or maybe [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Here is a nice article with code for an application similar to what you ask for [Multiuser Drawing Pad Built with Pure JavaScript/HTML5/Canvas](http://www.unionplatform.com/?page_id=2762)

Comment: I've already done what you said, or similar. The real problem is I don't know how to process all painting message well. I prepare to use a queue or something like that to implement different users' painting.  Do you have other suggestions on it?

Comment: You need to do the queue - JS is only giving a single thread of execution, so if something occur at the exactly the same time or their different is less than 10ms, you need to resolve than in server side.

Comment: @vincicat Thanks, I guess I have no choice now.

Comment: Anyway, your answer is good enough for others who try to make a new paint chat web app. So I mark yours as the best.

Comment: I've tried implementing it in a fashion which Jonas describes, and it works great when one user is painting, but not both at the same time, that creates weird painting patterns. I think in order for two users to paint at the exakt same time, two canvases must be used. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: @SoroushHakami: No, you don't need two canvases for this.

Comment: Say my client receives messages asynchronously on what to draw on the canvas. First it receives e message from client1 to start painting from coordinates 1,1. A millisecond later, it receives a message from client2 to move to 3,3. How will the client know not to process the second request until the first request is complete? I also tried having two separate contexts for one canvas but that didnt work out either.

Comment: @SoroushHakami: You can process a request before it's complete. E.g. if a user paints a long line in two minutes, it should send many messages to the server and the other clients should see the partial line. You have the `clientId` in every message, so you see from what user the message is from.

Comment: @Jonas I think I might know what the problem might be. You mention that "so you can broadcast the full path " . As it is, I am broadcasting ALL events, ie not only start and stop, but mere 'drag' events aswell. I suppose that every "draw" itself must be atomic, otherwise they can interfere with each other. Am I in the right ballpark now y'think?

Comment: @SoroushHakami: You can do it in different ways. In a line, there is no "stop", just a "lineTo" for every drag. I don't know your specific problem, and don't discuss it here, you can ask a new question.